# Is there are any ways an agent can see the number of pending chat requests on omni channel?

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud, omnichannel, lightning-console

I am facing a scenario where an agent can see 4 cases in the omni channel. The agent can not see if there are any pending cases in the queue unless the agent closes one case down from four.
Simply, i want the agent to see if there are any pending cases in the queue if the case number exceeds 4.

is there any ways to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is in Lightning Console which requires you to use Omni-Channel instead of the Live Agent component that was available for Classic. This is a supervisor function and would only be available in the Supervisor App of Omni-Channel by looking at unrouted chats (or chat transcripts as might be the case). You'd need to create custom permissions and sharing in order to be able to display this information in a component to an agent.

Comment: is there any way for an agent to see the number of pending chats in the queue, for example if there are 10 chats pending in the queue then agent could able to see number "10" displaying in the omni channel

Comment: The only way I know of would be to create a custom component that either calls a class that runs in system mode or provide Omni-Channel supervisor permissions to agents and either give them access to the Supervisor App or create a component to display chat backlog. That's the essence of my answer above.